# SARIMA - Sales predicitons

Tags: arima, multiple-seasonalities

My question is about seasonality with SARIMA. With data sales, there is (in my opinion) two factors to take into account. Sales have a week seasonality and also a trend throughout the year.

My question is, How to take those two factors into account?

For week seasonality I think it's related to m parameter. But how SARIMA understand that sometimes a product sells better in July? Do I need a set of Data with at least 2 years? Or is this related to SARIMAX and exog parameter?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been calling this "intra-weekly" and "intra-yearly seasonality". It's a case of [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities) - you may want to skim through that tag. There are specialized forecasting methods to cover this, like BATS or TBATS. (In a retail context, you may also need to account for calendar events that move through the year and for promotions.)

SARIMA cannot deal with multiple seasonalities. You could regress your time series on harmonic or other dummies to capture one kind of seasonality, then apply SARIMA to the residuals. But then you are already halfway to a TBATS model.